# Have how delete usage statistics of an app with adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-2.3

I want delete App usage statistics of my android
I know how to get its a simple command

```
adb shell dumpsys usagestats package com.x.x
```

but I need to clear the information of a specified app.
Any idea?